# How can I change text color of antd notification depending upon type?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, colors, antd, toast

How can I change text color of antd notification depending upon type. I want red color of notification if type is error and white color for other types. I am able to change background colors depending upon type but I dont know why I am unable to change text color.

This is my code that is working for background color, borders etc but I need to change text color when type of antd notification changes.

```html
import { notification } from "antd";

const openNotification = (title, message, type) => {
  notification[type]({
    message: title,
    description: message,
    style: { backgroundColor: type == "error" ? "red" : "white" },
    duration: 0,
  });
};

export default openNotification;
```

Comment: style: type === "error" ? {backgroundColor : "red" , color : "blue"} :  {backgroundColor : "pink" , color : "white"},

Comment: This does same as above which I mentioned, it changes background color but it doesn't effect text color. @FaizalHussain

Comment: You simply use the CSS property ```color``` for font color. ```{color: type=="error" ? "red":"black"```.  Or white, but I figure if your background color is white, users would not be able to see if the text is white too.

Comment: I mentioned same thing which you told, I dont know why but this is not working, color should change accordingly but it doesn't change. Other css properties work like if I change background or add border etc, but text color is not changing. @AnthonyDev220

Comment: @AbdullahAbbasi would you be able to provide a mini demo in codesandbox or any other platforms so that it reproduces your problem? Here is a codesandbox I created, https://codesandbox.io/s/customized-style-antd-4-21-6-forked-v3mp4m

Comment: Yes, this is the problem, text color changes this way but If I pass 'title', 'message', and type as a prop and call it somewhere else, then text color doesnt change. @AnthonyDev220

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you refer to the [API docs](https://ant.design/components/notification/#API), you'll see that `description` and `message` support ReactNode types. Why not make them `div`s and apply color styling on them?

```js
const openNotification = (title, message, type) => {
  notification[type]({
    message: (
      <div style={{ color: type === "error" ? "green" : "blue" }}>{title}</div>
    ),
    description: (
      <div style={{ color: type === "error" ? "green" : "blue" }}>
        {message}
      </div>
    ),
    style: { backgroundColor: type === "error" ? "red" : "white" },
    duration: 0
  });
};
```

[DEMO](https://codesandbox.io/s/customized-style-antd-4-21-7-forked-v0odwc?file=/demo.js)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a workaround you can try. You could add `className` and give its property conditionally,

```
const openNotification = (title, message, type) => {
  notification[type]({
    message: title,
    description: message,
    className: type == "error" ? "notification-error" : "notification",
    style: { backgroundColor: type == "error" ? "red" : "white" },
    duration: 0,
  });
};
```

And in your CSS, you could write to override what's given by the antd,

```
.notification-error {
    color: red;
}
.notification {
    color: black;
}
```

Comment: I tried this too before, but it just doesn't change text color, other CSS applies like changing background color, adding borders etc too. I think this has something to do with antd.